# Working Example Of Luminol Anomaly Detection And Correlation Library By Linkedin

Tags: python, python-2.7, time-series, anomaly-detection

Github Link Of Luminol Library: https://github.com/linkedin/luminol

Can anyone explain me with a sample code, how to use this module for finding anomalies in data set.

I want to use this module for finding the anomalies in my time series data.

P.S.: I tried the example 1 provided in README.md but getting error, so someone please provide me a working example for finding anomalies.

Example 1
Put anomaly scores in a list.

```
from luminol.anomaly_detector import AnomalyDetector
my_detector = AnomalyDetector(ts)
score = my_detector.get_all_scores()
anom_score = list()
for (timestamp, value) in score.iteritems():
    t_str = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(timestamp))
    anom_score.append([t_str, value])
```

Getting  `value error: (22, 'Invalid argument')  In line: t_str = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H :%M%S', time.localtime(timestamp))`

Using Python 2.7

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example works after adding `import time` and defining `ts`. The use of [time.localtime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.localtime) presumes your starting data uses unix time. Additional parameters for AnomalyDetector are noted [here](https://github.com/linkedin/luminol/blob/master/src/luminol/anomaly_detector.py#L25-L42). The available algorithms are defined [here](https://github.com/linkedin/luminol/blob/master/src/luminol/algorithms/anomaly_detector_algorithms/all.py#L14-L22). If `algorithm_name` is not specified, AnomalyDetector falls back to using the the [default_detector](https://github.com/linkedin/luminol/blob/master/src/luminol/algorithms/anomaly_detector_algorithms/default_detector.py) which uses a weighted sum of [exponential averages](https://github.com/linkedin/luminol/blob/master/src/luminol/algorithms/anomaly_detector_algorithms/exp_avg_detector.py#L23) and [derivatives](https://github.com/linkedin/luminol/blob/master/src/luminol/algorithms/anomaly_detector_algorithms/derivative_detector.py#L23). These [slides](https://conferences.oreilly.com/velocity/vl-ca-2016/public/schedule/detail/50247) might also be helpful.

data.csv

```
1490323038, 3
1490323048, 4
1490323058, 6
1490323068, 78
1490323078, 67
1490323088, 5
```

app.py

```
from luminol.anomaly_detector import AnomalyDetector
import time

# ts = 'data.csv'  # or
ts = { 
    '1490323038': 3,
    '1490323048': 4,
    '1490323058': 6,
    '1490323068': 78,
    '1490323078': 67,
    '1490323088': 5,
}

my_detector = AnomalyDetector(ts)
score = my_detector.get_all_scores()
anom_score = []

for (timestamp, value) in score.iteritems():
    t_str = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(timestamp))
    anom_score.append([t_str, value])

for score in anom_score:
    print(score)
```

Output:

```
['2017-03-23 19:37:18', 0.0]
['2017-03-23 19:37:28', 0.02482518793211144]
['2017-03-23 19:37:38', 0.06951052620991202]
['2017-03-23 19:37:48', 2.5187085350547482]
['2017-03-23 19:37:58', 1.201340494410737]
['2017-03-23 19:38:08', 0.9673414624904575]
```